# Im trying to create a list from a delimited text file

Tags: applescript

```
set definitionsPath to "/Users/toto/Desktop/Definitions.txt"

set defs to POSIX file definitionsPath

set temp to defs as string

set defs to read file temp using delimiter {"§"}
```

But it doesn't work. The AppleScript list isn't created

I've tried to fill the text file by using different approaches :

text1§ text2§ text3§

"text1"§"text2"§"text3"

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put each item in a new line for example

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Then read

```
set definitionsPath to "/Users/toto/Desktop/Definitions.txt"
set defs to paragraphs of (read definitionsPath as «class utf8»)
```

As almost all text files are UTF8 encoded it's crucial to add `as «class utf8»`, the default text encoding of AppleScript is MacRoman

Comment: Thank you very much vadian. You gave me the solution and without your help I wouldn't have looked in this direction.

Comment: @Lionel_A If the answer was helpful then go ahead and accept it.